# How to decouple Icecast web interface and mountpoints

Tags: icecast

It looks like default behavior is for Icecast to expose its web interface on the same address and port as any mountpoint.  E.g.:

```
  mountpoint = https://server.com/listentome
  web app = https://server.com/
```

I'd like to restrict the web interface to **only a certain IP address and TCP port** so that it is not accessible on the public IP.  E.g.:

```
  mountpoint = https://server.com/listentome
  web app = https://192.168.1.10:8000/
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create `<mount>` sections for the files/parts you want to be protected and enable `<authentication>`. Yes, it works on files too, not just streams. The XML transforms that show stream information are `status.xsl` and `status-json.xsl`.

For details please refer to the manual: https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-trunk/auth/

The other option is to remove those files and only use the web pages and raw XML within `/admin`.

Icecast 2.4 does not allow for separation of files and streams.

Comment: But even if I do both of the above, the default web interface is still open to the internet (if the stream is on the internet).  It seems strange to me that Icecast doesn't have a built-in way to optionally remove/hide this access and separate these two functions.  What I've done for the moment is to set the web root alias to a HTML page that redirects to our main website.  To further secure the server I'll have to move all the XSL files and change the config file accordingly.

Comment: Most of the time what people care about is hiding the listener numbers, for some reason. Pretty much all the other metadata is also available from the streams themselves, obviously. For making things completely oblique it's sufficient to point to an empty directory as webroot in the config. The admin API/Interface always requires authentication and a strong password is always a good idea. – I'm not sure what you mean by "still open" though. What are your real concerns here?

Comment: OK, I initially misunderstood the idea of removing the files in web root, in which case there would be no files to serve.  But, someone could still point to //myserver.com/admin, right?  My real concern is someone trying to poke around in the Icecast server and seeing stuff they don't need to see or finding vulnerabilities.